# Expectation of Riemann sum with integral inside

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, riemann-sum

I am trying to solve the following thing. I have two random processes $(X_t)$ and $(Y_t)$, on the interval $[0,T]$. For what is worth, $(X_t)$ is non-negative.

I want to show that 
$$ \lim_{\Delta_t\rightarrow 0}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\mathbb{E}\left[X_{t_{i+1}}\left(\int_{t_i}^{t_{i+1}}Y_tdt\right)^2\right] = 0 $$
(sum corresponding to a partition $0=t_0<t_1<\dots<t_n=T$, with $\Delta t=\max \Delta t_i$).

I have tried several approaches but can't just get there. I can show it without the expectation, i.e., pointwise, but using that $\max_{|a-b|\leq \Delta_t}|Y_a-Y_b|$ goes to 0 as $\Delta_t$ goes to $0$, but the proof doesn't seem to extend to the case with expectation.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Do you assume that the processes have continuous sample paths?

Comment: Yes, I can assume that

Comment: You will certainly need some additional integrability assumptions. Unless I'm missing something obvious, the expectation value might be infinite.

Comment: Sure we can add integrability assumptions as well. They will be fine in my special case.

Comment: It's kind of hard to guess which assumtions are (not) satisfied in your particular example. Please explain in more detail 1. the assumptions on the processes or 2. the particular application you are interested in.